# magento product description not saving changes

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Helloo guys!

I just moved my site to another server and I tried to modify some products description.

In backend the product description is saved but in frontoffice the old description still apears!

I would really aprecciate your help!

Ps: chache is disabled!

Comment: if its a configurable, make sure u modify the configurable product, not the children, also... always re-index.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?